# $F_\pi(\mathbb N)$ be periodic function set. Show $F_\pi(\mathbb N)\subseteq F(\mathbb N)$ ( Vector Space of Functions).

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

**Question**

> Let $F(\mathbb N)=\{f:\mathbb{N\to R}\}$ denote the vector space of functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$. The addition and scalar multiplication in $F(\mathbb N)$ are:$$(f+g)(n)=f(n)+g(n) \qquad (kf)(n)=k(f(n))$$ A function $f:\mathbb{N\to R}$ is called *periodic* if there is some number $k$ such that $f(n)=f(n+k)\; \forall n$.
> Let $F_\pi(\mathbb N)$ be the set of  periodic functions. Show that $F_\pi(\mathbb N)\subseteq F(\mathbb N)$.

I know how to solve the problem, however what I'm confused on is how I would go about putting a $Zero$ Vector within this function? My best guess is that $n=0$ would be the example, and the function of $f(0)$ would be the vector that I would need to prove is within the set $F(\mathbb N)$, however I'm skeptical that I even have the right idea within this problem, which isn't helped by the fact that the example doesn't show $n=0$ as a possible occurrence within these functions. (Although the problem does state that periodic functions like this are true For All $n$, however it doesn't give n a set, so I'm not sure I can include $0$)

Comment: If it is the "vector space" of functions, a function is a "single" vector; thus, presumably, the $0$ vector will be the function $\text {zero}(n)=0$ for every $n$.

Comment: If $p$ is the $LCM$ of the periods of $f_1,...,f_n$ then $p$ is a period of any linear combination of $f_1,...,f_n.$